# Use operators on JavaScript strings

Tags: javascript, string, variables, math, operators

I'm trying to get a segment of a URL. I start out with this:

```
 var url = "http://example.org/season-1";
 var url2 = url.replace('http://example.org/season-','');
```

I end up with a variable called `url2`, which is set to `1`.

From there, I'm trying to advance to the next season. I tried `url2 + 1`, `url2++`, etc. The result is `11`, when it should be `2`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"1"` is a string. You're concatting instead of adding.

You have to turn that `"1"` into an integer first, which you can do with `parseInt('1')`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `parseInt` like this:

```
// ...
url2 = parseInt(url2);
```